# Java 8 Predicates

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

Here is an example method that takes a Predicate as an argument:

```
void processFields(List<WebDataField> fields, Predicate<WebDataField> predicate) {
    for (WebDataField webDataField : fields) {
        boolean expectedCondition = predicate.test(webDataField);
    }
}
```

And I call the above function as:

```
processFields(fields, w -> w.getFieldName().length() > 5);
```

Another function:

```
public void doSomething(Object someObject,Predicate<T> predicateInstance){
    //doSomething method's code goes here
}
```

And on the calling side the method doSomething() will be called like this –

```
doSomething(someObjectInstance, Integer i-> i>10)
```

I checked the Java 8 documentation for String/Integer/Object etc and didn't find any of these class implementing the `Predicate<T>` interface. I don't know what I have missed in my Java 8 tutorial series, but I am not able to get this phenomenon:

1. How does the compiler allow the lambda expression if the target type has no direct connection with Predicate class?
2. Will the answer be same for both the above cases?

Answer (score 1):

The value of the lambda expression `(Integer i) -> i>1` is not `Integer`, so `Integer` doesn't have to implement `Predicate` in order for you to be able to pass that lambda expression to your method.

`Integer` is the type of the argument `i` of the lambda expression. `(Integer i) -> i>1` can represent any functional interface having a single method that takes an `Integer` argument and returns a `boolean`. Therefore it fits the `Predicate<Integer>` functional interface.

Your other lambda expression - `w -> w.getFieldName().length() > 5` - takes an argument of unspecified type, and returns a `boolean`. In order for it to pass compilation, the compiler must infer the type of `w` to be some class or interface having a `getFieldName()` method which returns an instance of some type having a `length()` method. When you pass your lambda expression to your `processFields` method, which expects a `Predicate<WebDataField>`, the compiler can infer that the type of the lambda expression's argument `w` is `WebDataField`.

Comment: Ok, so the (Integer i) -> i>1 will evaluate to a boolean, then how does this pass the compilation? Is boolean implementing predicate?

Comment: @aka Passing a lambda expression to a method (or assigning it to a variable) doesn't execute the method of the functional interface implemented by that lambda expression, so the type of the lambda expression is not a `boolean`, it's a `Predicate<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the first question:
The above lambda expression `i-> i>10` is a shorter way to express the following:

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = new Predicate<Integer>() {

  @Override
  public boolean test(Integer i) {
    return i > 10;
  }
};
```

which would be used then as follows:

```
Integer someObjectInstance = 1;
doSomething(someObjectInstance, predicate);
```

Thus the target type (`Integer`) has "*a direct connection with Predicate*".

Going on to the second question:
On `Predicate<T>` the `T` is a [generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) type parameter. Generic type parameters accept only reference types but not primitive types. Thus a `Predicate<T> p` always has to have an object instance as parameter (you called it *someObjectInstance*) of type `T`. If you want to test an `Integer` you do it this way:

```
Integer someObjectInstance = 1;
doSomething(someObjectInstance, i-> i>10);
```

But if you try to call the method with a primitive type integer (`int`) this will give a syntax error:

```
int integer = 0;
worker.doSomething(integer, i -> i > 10); // The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
```

But you can help the compiler by providing explicitly the generic type parameter. In this case it is `Integer`, the corresponding wrapping type of `int`. This will work because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

```
int integer = 0;
worker.<Integer> doSomething(integer, i -> i > 10);
```

But you said for "*String/Integer/Object etc ... didn't find any of these class implementing the Predicate*". For the primitive types there are dedicated predicate interfaces. For example: `IntPredicate`.
But they aren't extending the interface `Predicate<T>`. That's not possible since a definition like `IntPredicate extends Predicate<int>` is invalid. As mentioned above `int` is not acceptable as a generic type parameter.

To use an `IntPredicate` you can declare a method

```
  public <T> void doSomething(int i, IntPredicate intPredicate) {
    // doSomething method's code goes here
  }
```

and call it like this:

```
doSomething(integer, i -> i > 10);
```

To get an overview of the different predicate interfaces have a look on the package `java.util.function` [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html).